# Import orders from Magento 1 to Magento 2 live website

Tags: magento2, orders, migration

I have a Magento 2 shop in live and another shop in Magento 1. I'm preparing the migration of Magento 1 shop to Magento 2 in another website, so I will have 2 websites in Magento 2. How can I migrate the orders of Magento 1 shop to Magento 2? If I use the Data Migration Tool of Magento the orders save with website id 1 and I need to be save as website id 2.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply try import export which Magento gives by default or any other free extension must be their for you, just try on stage/local 1st

Comment: Do you know any free extension who let me import orders to Magento 2? By default magento dont give me to import orders.